# How to convert an arbitrary hash into an html table

Tags: html, perl

I have looked at [HTML::QuickTable](http://search.cpan.org/~nwiger/HTML-QuickTable-1.12/lib/HTML/QuickTable.pm) but AFAIK it supports only one-level-deep hash. To this module, I could not find a way to specify the `colspan` and `rowspan` for some headers in case of a multi-level hash. Is there some solution for this?

Consider this hash, that needs to be converted into a table like the one [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HxeK8/1/):

```
my $persons = {
          'Person1' => {
                    'Prop1' => {
                                  'X' => '8',
                                  'Y' => '8'
                                },
                    'Prop2' => {
                                   'X' => '5',
                                   'Y' => '5'
                               },
                    'Prop3' => {
                                   'X' => '0',
                                   'Y' => '0'
                               },
                    'Prop4' => {
                                   'X' => '10',
                                   'Y' => '10'
                               },
                    'Prop5' => {
                                   'X' => '1',
                                   'Y' => '12'
                               }
                    },
          'Person2' => {
                    'Prop1' => {
                                  'X' => '12',
                                  'Y' => '12'
                                },
                    'Prop2' => {
                                  'X' => '12',
                                  'Y' => '12'
                               },
                    'Prop3' => {
                                  'X' => '12',
                                  'Y' => '12'
                               },
                    'Prop4' => {
                                  'X' => '12',
                                  'Y' => '12'
                               },
                    'Prop5' => {
                                  'X' => '12',
                                  'Y' => '12'
                               }
                    }
        };
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472507/how-do-i-output-a-text-table-in-perl

Answer (score 0):

You checked [HTML:::Table](http://search.cpan.org/~ajpeacock/HTML-Table-2.08a/lib/HTML/Table.pm)?